# how to stop scrolling on mobile devices and why translations seems to stop it?

Tags: css, mobile, drag

Please take a look with a mobile device:

http://jsfiddle.net/stratboy/tk6ztzku/1/

This is an offcanvas prototype I'm building. Please excuse me for the cluttered css: it's a compiled version of an scss with imports.. Also it lacks of imported fonts.

Anyway, it works. Red buttons open a submenu. But on mobile devices there is a thing: BEFORE opening a sub, you can 'scroll', or better, drag, the menu left/right. AFTER opening the submenu, it works fine (meaning you cannot drag enymore left/right, only up/down).

So, maybe there's something that makes it stops and I'd like to find out and use that to stop lateral dragging from the beginning. On the code there's nothing special: js simply adds/remove classes (it's substantially and almost pure css offcanvas), and classes simply add translation:

```
  &.submenu .menu-box{
    @include translate(-$off_canvas_width, 0);
    @include translate3D(-$off_canvas_width, 0, 0);
  }
```

(dummy code otherwise they don't let me add the jfiddle link)

I tried to init .menu-box with a zero-translation but doesn't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

OK. This is only a partial answer, I'd still like to know how to really stop lateral dragging on mobile devices.

Anyway, the translation thing is not true: it doesn't stop anything, it stopped for other reasons.

To solve my problem I simply eliminated the real reason for lateral scrolling: content overflow. So I basically hide all the submenus on init (row 34):

```
this.submenus.hide();
```

(excuse me I must add some dummy code to add the jfiddle link...)

The working version is this:

http://jsfiddle.net/stratboy/tk6ztzku/4/

Note that I also added a no-scroll class to the body, but that's not related to the original question: it's only to prevent the body to scroll when the menu scrolling ends somewhere.

Tested on latest chrome, firefox, safari, android 4.x, latest ios, ie 9-11